# How I can solve this : One :: Num a => a -> Bool -> a in Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell, types

Define functions that have the following type signature!

```
One :: Num a => a -> Bool -> a

One = ?
```

I do not understand how a Num can be a bool and become again a Num. Could anybody help for me to understand and solve it.

Comment: It means you have to write a function that takes a number and a bool, and returns a number (of the same type as the original). There are lots of ways one could write such a function and I have no idea which one you are being asked to write.

Comment: The `Num` argument isn't a `Bool`; it's entirely independent of it. `One 3 True`, `One 4 False`, etc are examples of a call. Given that all integer literals have type `Num a => a`, it's trivial to define any number of functions that ignore both arguments are return whatever number you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how a Num can be a bool and become again a Num. Could anybody help for me to understand this.

Well, this would be the case if the grouping in the type was to the left, like so

```
one :: Num a => (a -> Bool) -> a
```

But actually, the grouping is to the right:

```
one :: Num a => a -> (Bool -> a)
```

So we need to find a way to turn an `a` type value into a way to turn a `Bool` value to an `a` type value.

Since we will have had this `a` type value, we could just return it:

```
one a = two 
  where
  two b = a
```

Do note that I had to change `One` to `one`. While `One` is syntactically a type in Haskell, `one` is a value which *has* a type. Which you show.

So what we did here is define the value `one`, which has this type. Or in Haskell,

```
one :: a -> (Bool -> a)
```

But wait, where did the `Num a =>` constraint go? We didn't use it at all, and that's why all we could do was to just return the `a`.

But what does it mean, for `a` to be a `Num`?

```
GHCi> :i Num

class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
  negate :: a -> a
  abs :: a -> a
  signum :: a -> a
```

So then, any `Num` has absolute value, and can be negated. Thus a possible definition is

```
one :: Num a => a -> (Bool -> a)
one a = two
  where
  two b | b      = negate a
        | otherwise = abs a
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working                                                                                               
f2 :: Num a => a -> Bool -> a
f2  x = one
    where
    one  = x

Comment: why did you try that? is that what I wrote in my answer? have you read through  my whole answer?

Comment: Could you write an example, because i still not understand this.

Comment: I already did. it's in the answer. how are you "trying" this? in GHCi? you should load a source file into it.

Comment: I dont understand your answer. It is too much for me.

Comment: so your question was too broad for you. how are you entering your definitions? where, in GHCi?

Comment: I tried it in ghci.

Comment: you should save your code in a source file and load it into GHCi.

Comment: I load the file in ghci and tried it. It give me this problem: Couldn't match expected type `Bool -> a' with actual type `a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          f2 :: forall a. Num a => a -> Bool -> a

Comment: you tried your code, with `f2`. now try mine, with `one` and `two`.

Comment: It is still not working. I tried with one and two.

Comment: sorry, had an error. I've edited with a fix. you can try the new code.

Comment: What I have to wrote in the consol to test it ?

Comment: e.g. `one 1 True`, `one (-2) (1>2)`.